# Is it allowed to wear a bulletproof vest in Hong Kong?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, regulations, hong-kong

Is it allowed to wear a bulletproof vest and a bulletproof helmet in Hong Kong. I mean in areas like the Airport (including beyond security, immigration etc.), roads, general public areas?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to try such a thing on an airport? It’s a recipe for detention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because attempting to impersonate security forces is not about traveling per se.

Comment: It is about traveling as I have to wear it in the airport.

Comment: @PeterM who said anything about "attempting to impersonate security forces"?

Comment: @ChrisH What class of people typically wear bullet proof vests and helmets *inside* secure areas of airports?

Comment: I'm asking this question for someone who is traveling to Hong Kong and has received death threats. So he needs to independently protect himself.

Comment: @DuraiArasan If your friend has concerns about death threats *inside* the secure area of an airport, then your friend has way more issues than simple death threats.

Comment: @PeterM I'm not suggesting OP's desire is remotely reasonable. But I'm far more inclined to believe they're... being excessively risk-averse, to put it politely... than that they're attempting to ensure they don't break any rules while impersonating security.

Comment: Maybe it's silly to wear it inside the airport. But I'm also asking about general areas in Hong Kong outside the airport.

Comment: @DuraiArasan If your friend's life is in danger, they need to be talking to a professional security consultant, not getting you to ask random people on the internet about the legality of bullet-proof vests. Furthermore, if travelling to Hong Kong will put their life in danger, the answer is quite simple: don't go to Hong Kong. Nothing they could possibly want to do there is more important than their own life.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is too serious a subject for the advice of random people on the internet to be appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

I decided to dig into this for the curiosity aspect and discovered [Why are bulletproof vests illegal in many countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14399/why-are-bulletproof-vests-illegal-in-many-countries)

Which led me to the wikipedia article [Bulletproof vest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest) which has a specific entry for [legality in Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest#Hong_Kong) which states:

> Under Schedule C (item ML13) of Cap. 60G Import and Export (Strategic
>   Commodities) Regulations, "armoured or protective equipment,
>   constructions and components" are not regulated "when accompanying
>   their user for the user’s own personal protection"

So according to random links on the internet it appears that your friend can bring such items into Hong Kong for their personal use.

However as I stated in my comment above, if your friend is this paranoid about personal safety then there are way more things going on than can be answered here.  Your friend needs to consult with a business that provides personal protection.

Note that this does not mean such items are legal in the country that your friend is *departing* from.  I also just saw [Hong Kong photographer arrested over bulletproof vest allowed to leave Thailand, still faces charges](https://www.hongkongfp.com/2015/09/07/hong-kong-photographer-arrested-for-bulletproof-vest-allowed-to-leave-thailand-still-faces-charges/)

> A Thai court on Monday said a Hong Kong photographer detained for
>   carrying a bullet proof jacket and helmet was free to leave the
>   country, although he still could face five years in jail on a weapons
>   charge.
>
> ...
>
> Both items are classified as weapons under Thai law and
>   Kwan was charged with breaching the country’s Arms Control Act.

Comment: @DuraiArasan,if you think this is helpful you can accept the answer.

Comment: The article you quote only says it is legal to carry them. That does not mean it is legal to wear them.